# How to make python run multiple processes/threads on different cores?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, multiprocessing

I have a python script that needs to run thousands of commands in the Linux command line in the fastest time possible. So I want to split each command out into a different thread/process, running them separately, and then spread out the load between all of my machine's cores.

I've tried using the threading and multiprocessing modules, and also subprocess.Popen, but I can't seem to force python to run it's processes and therefore the commands on different cores.

Can anybody help and/or recommend the best way for me to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
while True:

    # grab next section of data
    data = file.read(bytes_to_read)
    cmd_stream += data

    # remove dead processes
    if len(processes) >= max_processes:
        while (processes) and (processes[0].poll() is not None):
            del processes[0]

    while len(processes) < max_processes:
        # get new command, break if none
        new_cmd, cmd_stream = get_next_cmd(cmd_stream)
        if not new_cmd:
            break

        new_cmds = turn_args_into_cmd(new_cmd)
        for args in new_cmds:
            new_process = subprocess.Popen(args)
            processes.append(new_process)
```

I've also tried the following code in replace of the last section:

```
p = Process(target=run_cmd, args=(new_cmd,))
processes.append(p)
p.start()
```

Comment: You should look into the multiprocessing modules and more particularly, the pool method. You can specify the numer of CPU you want to use etc.

Comment: Clarification: `multiprocessing` module allows you to specify the number of processes you want not the number of CPUs. The OS is responsible for scheduling across the CPUs. But this is also true with any `Process`.